# Merging Data Table in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, .net, crystal-reports, dataset

I am trying to show a report by querying records from a table following the steps given at

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166291/Generate-a-report-using-Crystal-Reports-in-Visual

I am getting an error thrown at the line

**ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);**

as does not contain a definition for 'Tables' and no extension method 'Tables' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

in the below code. Please help.

Emp is the xsd file name (Emp.xsd) in which Dataset

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportDocument rptDoc = new ReportDocument();
        Emp ds = new Emp(); // Emp is the xsd file name (Emp.xsd)
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // Just set the name of data table
        dt.TableName = "EmployeeStats";
        dt = AB.GetEEmpStats((int)Session["EmpID"]); //Call function to get the     employee statistics

        ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< Error at this line

        // .rpt file path
        rptEmpStat.Load(Server.MapPath("EmpStats.rpt"));
        //dataset to the report viewer.
        rptDoc.SetDataSource(ds);
        Emp.ReportSource = rptDoc;
        Emp.RefreshReport();

    }
```

The code for GetEEmpStats is below

```
 public DataTable GetEEmpStats(int ID)
    {
        //Connection string 
        //string sqlCon = <***************>;

        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(sqlCon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        DataSet ds = null;
        SqlDataAdapter adapter;
        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            //Stored procedure 
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_getEmpDetails";
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // input parameter 

            SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter();
            parameter1.ParameterName = "@ID";
            parameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int;
            parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            parameter1.Value = ID;

            // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
            cmd.Connection = Con;
            ds = new DataSet();
            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(ds, "EmpDet");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            if (Con.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                Con.Close();
        }
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Comment: Your explanation is a little bit confusing : from your code, what's tdd.EmpStat ? what's tdd.EmpStat ? Does DataTable dt has the same schema as DataSet's DataTable ?

Comment: Is dt and ds.Tables[0] schema same?

Comment: thanks HichemC & Asif for responding.. pls check my question now.. should be clear to you.. pls help

Comment: Provide AB.GetEEmpStats() function code.

Comment: HichemC.. i have added the function code to my question.. pls help